# Returning entries that contain both categories

Tags: craft3, categories, relatedto, query

I'm creating a filter and would like to return entries that must contain multiple categories (and behavior, not or). A sample url would be /events?cat=2,3.

```
{% set eventCat = craft.request.getParam('cat') %}
{% set events = craft.entries.relatedTo(eventCat).all() %}
```

Gives me "or" behavior and

```
{% set eventCat = craft.request.getParam('cat') %}
{% set events = craft.entries.relatedTo('and', eventCat).all() %}
```

Doesn't give me any results.

**(updated to reflect Craft 3 syntax, thanks Robin!)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% set eventCats = craft.request.getParam('cat') %}
{% set eventCats = eventCats|split(',') %}

{% set cats = [] %}

{% for eventCat in eventCats %}
    {% set cats = cats|merge([{element: eventCat}]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% if cats|length > 0 %}
    {% set cats = ['and']|merge(cats) %}
{% endif %}

{% set events = craft.entries.relatedTo(cats) %}
```

Shout out to Stephen Hamilton who came up with this answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer for Craft 2

Your final result should not look like `relatedTo('and', '1,2')` but

```
relatedTo('and, 1, 2')
```

Or

```
relatedTo(['and', 1, 2])
```

So you just need to do

```
relatedTo('and,' ~ param)
```

Keep in mind to code defensively, so you might want to check if your query param is not null or something

#### Answer for Craft 3

```
relatedTo(['and', ['element' => 1], ['element' => 2]])
```

Comment: "Argument #2 is not an array" for any of these syntaxes. Is it because of how craft 3 has changed the relations syntax? Or am I being a goober somehow?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
{% set eventCats = craft.request.getParam('cat')|split(',') %}
{% set events = craft.entries.relatedTo(['and']|merge(eventCats)).find() %}
```

Comment: I'm getting an "Argument #2 is not an array" error - eventCats is definitely an array, is this a syntax error?